# List all user email ids based on role_name in magento 2?

Tags: magento2, user-roles, user, email-translation

In Magento 2,
We want to list all **user email id's** by using their **role_name**.

How we can achieve in one collection with optimal way?

Thanks!

Comment: What do you mean by `role_name`

Comment: Yes @Priyank we want users email ids by role_name

Comment: You mean admin users?

Comment: @Priyank admin side, lets consider there are 2 roles like: HOD, Operator. suppose if my passing Operator role then related  to same group user email should list.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can create a helper like below and pass the role name to filter it.

```
public function getUserByRole($roleName)
{
    /** @var $userCollection \Magento\User\Model\ResourceModel\User\Collection*/
    $userCollection->getSelect()->joinLeft(
        ['role' => $userCollection->getTable('authorization_role')],
        "main_table.user_id = role.user_id",
        ["role_name"]
        )->where("role.role_name = ". $roleName);
    return $userCollection;

}
```

By calling the above helper you will have collection of all the users of respective role.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 3):

**try below code:**

```
$roleName = "Administrators";
$objectManager =  \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$roleModel = $objectManager->create('Magento\Authorization\Model\Role');
$userModel = $objectManager->create('Magento\User\Model\User');
$roleModel = $roleModel->load($roleName, 'role_name');
if($roleModel->getId()) {
    $userIds = $roleModel->getRoleUsers();
    foreach($userIds as $userId) {
        $user = $userModel->load($userId);      
        print_r($user->getEmail());
        echo "<br>";                                   
    }
}
```

**Multiples Role name**

```
  $rolesModel = $objectManager->create('Magento\Authorization\Model\ResourceModel\Role\Collection');
  $rolesModel->addFieldToFilter('role_name', array('in' => array('Administrators','xyz')));

  if($rolesModel->getSize()) {
      foreach($rolesModel as $roleModel) {
          $userIds = $roleModel->getRoleUsers();
            foreach($userIds as $userId) {
                $user = $userModel->load($userId);      
                print_r($user->getEmail());
                echo "<br>";                                   
            }
      }
  }
```

Comment: if I want to use multiple roles, how could I use it?
e.i. $roleName = ("Administrators",''xyz'');

Comment: @Utsav Gupta Please check updates ans

Answer (score 2):

After digging , I got solution like this:

```
<?php
    namespace Custom\ProductApproval\Helper;

    use Magento\Authorization\Model\RoleFactory;
    use Magento\User\Model\UserFactory;


    class Data extends \Magento\Framework\App\Helper\AbstractHelper {

        protected $roles;
        protected $user;
        protected $objectManager;

        const ROLES_NAMES = "HOD Merchandising";

        public function __construct(\Magento\Framework\App\Helper\Context $context, \Magento\Backend\Model\Session $session, RoleFactory $roles, UserFactory $user
        ) {

            parent::__construct($context);
            $this->_session = $session;
            $this->roles = $roles;
            $this->user = $user;
            $this->objectManager = $objectManager;
        }


        public function getEmailUserByRole() {
            //$roleName = "HOD Merchandising";
            $userEmail = array();
            $roleModel = $this->roles->create();
            $userModel = $this->user->create();
            $roleModel = $roleModel->load(self::ROLES_NAMES, 'role_name');
            if ($roleModel->getId()) {
                $userIds = $roleModel->getRoleUsers();
                foreach ($userIds as $userId) {
                    $user = $userModel->load($userId);
                    $userEmail[]= $user->getEmail();
                }

            }
            return $userEmail;
        }

    }
```